# Color problem with Log transform to brighten dark area. Why and how to fix?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, image-enhancement

So I try to enhance this image by applying log transform on it
[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TdOu.jpg)
The area where there are bright white color turns into color blue on the enhanced image.
[enhanced image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaIDs.jpg)

```
path = '...JPG'
image = cv2.imread(path)
c = 255 / np.log(1 + np.max(image))    
log_image = c * (np.log(image + 1))

# Specify the data type so that
# float value will be converted to int
log_image = np.array(log_image, dtype = np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('img.JPG', log_image)
```

There's also a warning: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log

I tried using other type of log (e.g log2, log10...) but it still show the same result. I tried changing dtype = np.uint32 but it causes error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same cause for the two problems

Namely this line

```py
log_image = c * (np.log(image + 1))
```

`image+1` is an array of `np.uint8`, as `image` is. But if there are 255 components in image, then `image+1` overflows. `256` are turned into 0. Which lead to `np.log(imag+1)` to be `log(0)` at this points. Hence the error.
And hence the fact that brightest parts have strange colors, since they are the ones containing `255`

So, since log will have to work with floats anyway, just convert to float yourself before calling log

```py
path = '...JPG'
image = cv2.imread(path)
c = 255 / np.log(1 + np.max(image))    
log_image = c * (np.log(image.astype(float) + 1))

# Specify the data type so that
# float value will be converted to int
log_image = np.array(log_image, dtype = np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('img.JPG', log_image)
```

[image]

Comment: Note that you could achieve the same result by adding `1.0` instead of `1` to image. Find that is less readable, and not faster.